# Where to use Language hints in google-vision text-detection api?

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

So I know that google-vision api supports multiple language for text-detection. And by using the code below I can detect english language from image. But according to google I can use the parameter language hints to detect other languages. So where exactly am I suppose to put this parameter in the code below?

```
def detect_text(path):
    """Detects text in the file."""
    from google.cloud import vision
    imageContext = 'bn'
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(imageContext)

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
    print('Texts:')

    for text in texts:
        print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))

        vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                    for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])

        print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))


detect_text('Outline-of-the-Bangladesh-license-plates_Q320.jpg')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
response = client.text_detection(
    image=image,
    image_context={"language_hints": ["bn"]},  # Bengali
)
```

See ["ImageContext"](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1p3beta1#google.cloud.vision.v1p3beta1.ImageContext) for more details.